# Where can I find the latest /jsbin/www-widgetapi file?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm currently loading the YouTube API like so:

```
$(function () {
    //  This code will trigger onYouTubePlayerAPIReady
    $('<script>', {
        src: 'https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflwt8QCF.js',
        async: true
    }).insertBefore($('script:first'));
});
```

I was looking at the YouTube demo page, https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo, and I noticed in their source that they were using a different URL to load their widget API:

```
<script src="https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vfl4qCmf3.js" async></script>
```

I thought that this might be a more up-to-date version of their API. So, I swapped it out, but I receive an error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: YTConfig is not defined

I'm left wondering which of these is the correct location, if either, to be loading the most up to date widgetapi data from. Is there a location for this info?

Answer (score 1):

to get the latest API version I suggest to use example from YT reference:

```
 var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

this'll make sure the latest version is being loaded

if you really need to grab latest version for some reason just check this url:

https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api

and get it from the source code